# Cucumber test tables grow too long

Tags: datatable, cucumber, spreadsheet

I'm working on a set of Cucumber tests whose test table has the potential to grow a lot.  Example below with this form:

```
Feature: Login Action with a Named User

Scenario Outline: Succesful first login with valid credentials
Given User is on Foo LoginPage
#   And User has recently registered
When User clicks on Start Session
    And User inputs "<user>" and "<pass>"
Then I validate that "<user_full>" appears as profile name
    And Mi perfil icon is displayed

Examples:
    |user       |pass   |user_full  |
    |foo@bar.com|Test123|Foo Bar    |
```

I mean, with this simple login the Data Table has three parameters.  But when I start filling out forms, the data table can easily grow to thirty, forty parameters.

I have thought of rewriting the test case like described below.  This way, there are at most two parameters in the test table: the test case name and the user email, which are kind of like a primary key.

Then, data is fetched from a spreadsheet using these two parameters, to fill out a HashMap which is accessed by the rest of the test case.

```
Feature: Login Action with a Named User

Scenario Outline: Succesful first login with valid credentials
Given User is on Foo LoginPage
#   And User has recently registered
When User logs into app with "<user>"
Then I validate user information appears in profile name
    And Mi perfil icon is displayed

Examples:
    |TC_NAME |user       |
    |TC01    |foo@bar.com|
    |TC02    |fee@bar.com|
```

Spreadsheet looks like this:

[Data Pool spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU5y2.png)

Any thoughts?  have you used something different to avoid having a long data table in your Cucumber definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Kyle's answer, I dug into Cucumber documentation, which led me to use inline pipe tables for each step, instead of having forty columns in the Examples section, like this:

```
...
Scenario Outline: Compose an email in Gmail
Given I am logged onto gmail with:
 |user | pwd |
 |foo  | bar |
When I click the compose button
 And enter user email, subject and message as:
  |to  | subject | message |
  |fuu | subj    | ...     |
...
```

One can see how when lots more fields are input, data becomes manageable.
Plus, there's neat tool called Tidy Gherkin that can align pipe tables, so that's a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long list of parameters in your Scenario tables, you're most likely doing something wrong.

Cucumber is a tool built for conversations, and less about the tests in the background. It's about having a requirements document that can be executed. If nobody can understand the documentation (which would be difficult with the amount of scrolling right 40 columns would require), it's been written in the wrong way.

It'd either use more scenarios instead of writing a massively complex table, or shorten the scenario you have written (which is usually the better way to work).

Programmatically, excel sheets, switch statements and objects are great ways of collecting test data together using different switches. Try using these instead, and not only will everything look cleaner, but it'll make it more understandable.